# Battlemasters strikes clarification

Tags: dnd-5e, critical-hit, combat-maneuver, battle-master

In the Player's Handbook for DND 5e some of the maneuvers (distracting, disarming, menancing strike etc.) for the battlemaster fighter have this writen at the start:

> When you hit a creature with a weapon attack, you can expend one superiority die to [...] (frighten, disarm, distract) [...] You add the superiority die to the attack’s damage roll [...]

I interpret this as meaning that you can decide to make a maneuver of this type after you have already rolled your attack hit, and that means you could potentially spare the superiority dice for attacks when you rolled a 20 and crit. Am I correct in this interpretation?

Comment: @Vist, I'm voting to close on this because I believe it is a duplicate of the cited question. Can you review that question and confirm if it provides the answer you require. If not, please edit your question to address what you're unsure of. Thanks!

Comment: Yes it provides the awnser. This question may be closed.